# Binary math in IBM i RPGLE

Tags: c#, binary, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am trying to decipher an old piece of code from RPGLE so that I can convert it to C#.
Here is the code in question:

```
D                 DS                        
D  S2DATE                 1      6  0       
D  S2DA                   1      6          
D                                     DIM(6)

D                 DS                 
D  WI                     1      2B 0
D  WIBIN                  2      2 

C                   DO        6             X     
C                   CLEAR                   WI    
C                   MOVE      S2DA(X)       WIBIN 
C                   MULT      X             WI    
C                   ADD       WI            S2PASS
C                   END
```

S2DATE is a numeric input field on a screen and contains a value of 081523

```
EVAL s2da    
S2DA(1) = '0'
S2DA(2) = '8'
S2DA(3) = '1'
S2DA(4) = '5'
S2DA(5) = '2'
S2DA(6) = '3'
```

When I execute this code, these are the results for each element:

```
When X = 1:  WIBIN = '0'
             WI    = 0240
When X = 2:  WIBIN = '8'
             WI    = 0248
When X = 3:  WIBIN = '1'
             WI    = 0241 
When X = 4:  WIBIN = '5'
             WI    = 0245 
When X = 5:  WIBIN = '2'
             WI    = 0242 
When X = 6:  WIBIN = '3'
             WI    = 0243
```

From what I can tell, it looks like the data structure is trying to redefine the single character of WIBIN into a binary field - but these are not the binary values for these characters (I don't understand where the "240" value is coming from). This will make it difficult to convert the code to C# if the values are not actually binary.
I can't simply remove/subtract 240 from the WI value since this is from code that is in production. I am just trying to replicate the results in C#.

Any help in understanding what is going on (or how to duplicate the result in C#) would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

A fun challenge!

Here's one version of a platform independent C equivalent. It doesn't assume that '0' is 240, it subtracts '0' from the byte and then adds 240.

```
int s2dateNum = 81523;
char buf[11];
char s2date[6];
int s2pass = 0;
int i;
int len;
int start;

// Get s2dateNum in a string, length 6, with leading zeros
sprintf (buf, "%d", s2dateNum);
len = strlen(buf);
start = 6 - strlen(buf);
memset (s2date, '0', sizeof(s2date));
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
   s2date[start + i] = buf[i];
}

// do the weird processing
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
   // multiply the EBCDIC value of each byte ('0' = 240)
   // by the 1-origin index of the byte and add it to s2pass
   s2pass += ((s2date[i] - '0') + 240) * (i + 1);
}
```

Comment: (I don't know C#. Hopefully a C version will help.)

Comment: To be fair can be declared char* buf = "081523"; But if you want through printf with the addition of leading 0, then sprintf (buf, "%06d", s2dateNum);

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what that data structure overlay is doing and those are the correct values for those characters in EBCDIC.

[EBCDIC to ASCII](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.3?topic=tables-ebcdic-ascii)